# What additional material do i need for the installation of my powermeter?

Tags: shimano, crankset, power

I bought the following powermeter: https://www.mantel.com/de/4iiii-precision-105-r7000-left and shortly after i had to Switch bikes.

I (will) have the following bikes:

Bike1 (current bike): https://www.boc24.de/p/compel-rr-100/213327/#itemId=213327-1

Bike2 (potential): https://www.canyon.com/de-at/gravel-bikes/all-road/grail/grail-6/2369.html

My first bike has a shimano 105 crankset. The Canyon a Shimano RX600, see https://www.canyon.com/de-at/gravel-bikes/all-road/grail/grail-6/2369.html#all-components-section-tab.

#### The Installation of the powermeter:

I watched the following video:

and feel like i am missing parts like: https://www.mantel.com/de/shimano-tl-fc16-hollowtech-2-ii-crank-cap-tensioning-installation-tool and maybe a second one?

So i went to the bike shop where i bought my bike and they said the powermeter would not fit the bike. I am a bit surprised, because i have a shimano 105 crankset on the bike and the powermeter says shimano 105. I am not sure what the r7000 specification is for and if it would fit the Canyon as well, but ok.

**Question:**

If i can savely assume the bike shop was wrong, which material am i missing to install the powermeter?

The powermeter:

[image]

The current crank:

[image]

Where to put the crank on:
[image]

Comment: Could it be that you *don't* have a Shimano crankset? The [Bike1](https://www.boc24.de/p/compel-rr-100/213327/#itemId=213327-1) link shows an image with an FSA crank (with a Shimano 105 rear derailleur). Are you perhaps confused by that? Or did you install a Shimano 105 crankset yourself on Bike1?

Comment: The photo is of a FSA crank.

Comment: ah, stupid me. So i guess it wont fit on thereP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No additional materials will solve this situation unfortunately.
On the [COMPEL RR 10.0](https://www.boc24.de/p/compel-rr-100/213327/#itemId=213327-1) bike you have an FSA crankset, *not* a Shimano 105 crankset.