# Which bike independent powermeter to choose for non-click pedals?

Tags: pedals, power, clicking

I (will) have the following bikes:
Bike1 (current bike): https://www.boc24.de/p/compel-rr-100/213327/#itemId=213327-1
Bike2 (potential): https://www.canyon.com/de-at/gravel-bikes/all-road/grail/grail-6/2369.html

My current powermeter was bought for an older bike and does not fit the current bike. I would like to buy bike2 and a new powermeter, that fits two bikes (i assume buying two seperate powermeters to be way more expensive).
Currently i prefer pedal cups, because i can wear normal shoes that way and hike a bit if i do Multi day trips. But i might consider buying click pedals in the future.

Potential solution / What i tried/researched:
I could buy a pedal powermeter like: https://www.bikeinn.com/radfahren/garmin-vector-3s-pedal-mit-powermeter/136784484/p?belboon=2106121959529460465&utm_medium=afiliados&utm_source=455741.
That would be bike Independent and i would have the option to use click pedals later on.

I found that there might be an Adapter to use pedal Cups on click pedals? (https://www.rennrad-news.de/forum/threads/pedalhaken-f%C3%BCr-klick-system.28143/, https://forum.tour-magazin.de/showthread.php?99146-Xtreme-Touring-Adapter), (German source, sry).

Question:

Which powermeter / pedal / crank System should i consider?

Comment: What's the power meter that won't fit on the current bike, and why won't it fit on your proposed new bike?

Comment: @R.Chung https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77225/what-additional-material-do-i-need-for-the-installation-of-my-powermeter

Comment: Are you really planning to swap pedals before every ride?

Comment: would be open for that, yes. Assuming you mean before  every bike swap?

Answer (score 1):

Any crank-based or (rear) hub-based powermeter will do. Powermeters built into pedals are not the only ones available as you seem to suggest. Be aware though that powermeters are likely to be quite expensive and overkill on an economy range bicycle.

I might just add that the possibly cheapest way to add a powermeter would be to replace the left crank with one that carries a sensor. They are available over a wide range of cranks from most manufacturers. The only prerequisites are that the interface matches and the length is identical

Comment: This question requires more detail. What are Click pedals?  Are you talking about a crank based power meter?  Why are you concerned with power for an economy bike?

Comment: “ Powermeters do not work with pedals only” Could you elaborate? There are quite a few power meter pedals out there for both road and MTB.

Comment: Most cyclists have a budget to work to, and a power meter has the possibly of making the rider on an $800 bike faster than if they purchased an $1800 bike with no meter - not instantly, but the benefits would out last the more expensive bike.

Comment: @DwightJ.Browne: The author of the question uses the German terminology 'click' pedals meaning clipless pedals.

Comment: Klick is probably familiar to anyone who's done German mail order shopping, but what are Cups?

Comment: @ojs: Although I live next door to Germany (common border) I've never heard the word in the context of cycling. It may be some local term for those strapless clips that just 'cup' the toes, quite usual in the early day of MTB.